# Set Xs & Ys based on device in Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am building an app with several buttons and images.  I have set positions of buttons, images and scroll bars with absolute Xs & Ys.  And obviously those values would need to change based on the device (tablet, phone, etc.).  Can you help me understand the best way to do this in Flex?

This is a snippet of code that I am working on.  Would like the X & Y values to be set based on the device.

```
    <s:Rect id="TopBannerLandscapePhone" includeIn="landscapePhone" x="0" y="0" width="480" height="64">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0x0065a4"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flex [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) object gives you, among other things, `screenDPI`, `screenResolutionX`, and `screenResolutionY`.  You could use those to calculate your desired X and Y coordinates for your display objects.

You could also put your display objects in `<s:VGroup>` or `<s:HGroup>` containers (or set the `layout` property on plain `<s:Group>` containers.

Comment: Thanks.  I wound up using V & H Group containers which worked really well.  I am struggling to to place icons in the horizontal.  I have a VGrp with 1 Rect width = 100% & height =100% with a fill color.  I want to place an App Settings icon in that same area defined by the Rect but justified to right (say 20 pixels from the right edge).  I will create a new Q for this issue.  Thanks again